# How to escape ],[ sequence in java?

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee

While writing code in java, I need to split string with "],[" . Below is my code.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            int i=0;
            String line;
            line = reader.readLine();
            String[] split = line.split("],[");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(split[0]);
            String joined = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(joined);

        }
```

Please help here.

Comment: `line.split("\\],\\[");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the opening square bracket because `[` is a special meta character in  regex represents the start of a character class.

```
String[] split = line.split("],\\[");
```

`]` will match a literal `]` symbol when there is no start of the character class symbol `[` exists before `]`.

Comment: `]` is a special regex character, too.  I'd be surprised if you didn't get an error about mismatched brackets if it is not escaped but even if it works in Java today, the proper thing to do is escape it anyway.

Comment: `]` will loose its special meaning when there is no `[` symbol preceding in the regex you defined. Could you remove the downvote?

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a wise thing to do.  There are many different regex systems and the proper thing to do is escape both.  I have seen errors from regex parsers about mismatched parenthesis so you can't always depend on a character "losing its special meaning".

Comment: @BrianWhite it's all depends upon the location where we put the `]` symbol in the regex. And we are not talking about any other regex flavours, since the question is clearly tagged as java.

Comment: In all other regex flavors also it's completely based on the location.

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the `[`. Like:

```
line.split("\\],\\[");
```

Your code would be:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        int i=0;
        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();
        String[] split = line.split("\\],\\[");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(split[0]);
        String joined = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(joined);

    }
```